# Imbalanced classification or Regression? What is the best approach to my A/B testing related problem?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression, class-imbalance, ab-test

The context of the problem is A/B testing of two new versions of a game. I have a structured dataset (50000 rows x 22 columns) from the game designers that represents data with respect to two versions of the game: A and B. The rows represent individual players, and there are several categorical features (c*) and continuous features (n*). One of the important columns is the monetization (in-game purchases) obtained from the players. **The end goal is to be able to recommend a version A or B to each player, such that the monetization would be maximized.**

```
raw_df_columns: 'id', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5', 'c6', 'game_version', 'n1', 'n2',
'n3', 'n4', 'n5', 'n6', 'n7', 'n8', 'n9', 'n10', 'n11', 'n12', 'n13',
'monetization'
```

**Issues:**

The most important problem is that the version of the game (A or B) in the 'game_version' column is *not the end label*. It is simply the version that was issued to the person. I do not have the required labels directly to model it as a classification problem.

Therefore my initial approach to this was to attempt it as a regression problem. I did an EDA, eliminated some non-essential features and tried to predict 'monetization' using the rest of the features (except 'id' which has no correlation). The prediction accuracy is very good, but the problem is that the feature 'game_version' is more or less being ignored in this prediction. Or with some ML models it seems to have a very simplistic relationship, which is wrong.

Finally, in most cases A is better than B (has more monetization than the best of B), except for a small minority (~ 190 cases out of 50000) where B is better than A. This also makes it very difficult for the ML algorithms to zero in on such cases.

**Ask:**

What is the best approach that I should take for this problem? How do I obtain the *recommended* version of the game for a given player?

I can also provide additional details or clarifications if needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if the rest features (not issued game_version) are unique to each A/B version, then run an ML algorithm on these features to see what features players like most -> more money and infere the version from the features

Comment: Unfortunately no other features of the game are known. The rest of the features in the table refer to the players themselves.

Comment: Is time played by each player (whatever the version) in your data? If so this is an important feature that can predict game satisfaction -> monetisation (for that version)

Comment: Actually yes, the time played by each player is also given. It is directly correlated to the monetization. However, this still does not tell me how to choose the version of the game. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Sometimes we tend to over-complicate things. If people consistently spent more time on a specific version, simply choose that version